# Tableau Dashboard Building

Tags: tableau-api

I am very new to Tableau and I have an requirement to build an Data Quality Dashboard. I was wondering I can get some assistance in developing this.

Details:

1st requirement - To show a visual of all fields in the table with their appropriate counts of nulls/valid values/invalid values

Table name: 
Customers

Fields: 
- Name
- Address
- CustomerCategory
- DOB
- CustomerType

So I want three checks with counts to be done, Nulls, Valid Values, Invalid Values

The end result I would like is a stacked bar chart (x axis - count/percentage, y axis - field name). Each bar on the chart will represent one field e.g. Name or DOB...so on and will comprise of three counts of the three checks I have mentioned above and will total up to 100%. And it will also have two filters  - activity_month, provider_code

What is the best way in doing this? And if I need to create a calculated fields what's the optimum way?

Option 1

Do I need to create a calculated field for each field for each check?

e.g.   Name_null           - Total count null values 
       Name_invalid        - Total count invalid values 
       Name_valid          - Total count valid values

```
  CustomerCategory      - Total count null values 
  CustomerCategory      - Total count invalid values 
  CustomerCategory      - Total count valid values
```

In this option this would create many calculated fields.

Option 2

Do I create three fields with their total respective counts per check for all fields:

e.g.   Total_Null
       Total_Invalid
       Total_Valid

I coded this previously in SQL and brought it to Tableau data source and reliased I need row level data which is a requirement for the next visual Requirement 2

SQL example

SELECT

'CustomerCategory' AS 'field',
SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'null', 
SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory NOT IN ('01', '1','02','2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'invalid',
SUM(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory IN ('01', '1','02','2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'valid',
der_activity_month,
der_provider_code

FROM Customers

GROUP BY 
activity_month,
provider_code

UNION

SELECT

'DOB' AS 'field',
SUM(CASE WHEN DOBIS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'null', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DOB = '1900/01/01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'invalid',
SUM(CASE WHEN DOB <> '1900/01/01' OR aea_initial_assessment_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'valid',
der_activity_month,
der_provider_code

FROM Customers

GROUP BY 
activity_month,
provider_code

If I were to go with the second option how do I code to get the Total count of nulls and Total count of Invalid values and Total count of valid values in Tableau?

2nd requirement:

Show a dynamic drill down per field visual on a bar chart to show the total count of invalid and null values.

E.g.

CustomerCategory
Valid values 01, 1, 02, 2

So on the bar chart I would like to show invalid values which are not in the above valid value list. And also count of nulls

---

Reading the above, I would appreciate if anyone can give me the guidance how to build the dashboard correctly.

Much appreciated and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**1st requirement:**

You can go with Option 2. Drag the *Field* column on to **Columns** shelf and *Measure Values* on to **Rows** shelf then remove the *SUM(Number of Records)* from *Measure Values* pane. Then drag the *Measure Names* on to **Color** Marks (if *Measure Names* is already present with **Detail** Marks then remove it). For filters you can drag **der_activity_month and der_provider_code** fields on to **Filters** shelf and then Select *Show Filter*. You can choose the Colors for *Measure Names(Null, Invalid, Valid)*.

**2nd requirement:**

Make one more sheet and drag the Field column on to **Columns** shelf and **Create Calculated Field** with an expression *Invalid*+*Null* and drag this Calculated Field on to **Rows** shelf, make sure that it is SUM(Calculated Field) and it should be *Continuous(Green Color)*.

For drill down, go to **Worksheet** on Top Menu, **Actions** > **Add Action(choose Filter)**. Then under **Source Sheets:** Select The main sheet(1st sheet) and under **Target Sheets:** Select the 2nd sheet and Choose *Show all values* on right side then click *OK*.

At last to create **Dashboard**  simply drag the 1st sheet on to Dashboard then select the filters(if they are not already selected).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and let me try your suggested answers. Much appreciated